# Converting a solution based on for loop in python to Lambda, Lists?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, lambda, list-comprehension

I am python newbie who needs help in understanding, converting a solution which I have written via for loops to one more efficient (lambda or list comprehension).

I have two data frames:

Client_mapping: (Sum of options for a specific Category & Rank is always equal to one):

| Client_Category | Client_Rank | Client_Option | M1 | M2 | M3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Retail | Gold | Stay | 0.3 | 0 | 0 |
| Retail | Gold | Leave | 0 | 0.3 | 0.4 |
| Retail | Silver | Leave | 0.5 | 0.5 | 0 |

Client_detail (Breakdown of Client ID at Category & Rank):

| Client_Category | Client_Rank | Client_ID | Client_Category_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Retail | Gold | 1234 | 4 |
| Retail | Gold | 2345 | 4 |
| Retail | Gold | 3456 | 4 |
| Retail | Gold | 4567 | 4 |
| Retail | Silver | 5678 | 3 |
| Retail | Silver | 6789 | 3 |
| Retail | Silver | 7890 | 3 |

Essentially I have to match the Client Category & Ranks between two data frames and assign the month and option to each client. This must be done by using math floor function, with any residual count from decimal being assigned to last month (which is dynamic to each category and option).

The output should look like:
Joining Client Mapping with Client details to determine whether a client will leave or stay and if so which month. Take Client ID 1234, who is tagged as Staying from M1 (4 employees * 0.3) where Client 3456, 4567 are tagged as Leaving at M3 (one is from left over residual decimal spots from using floor and other from 0.4*4)

| Client_Category | Client_Rank | Client_ID | Client_Option | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Retail | Gold | 1234 | Stay | M1 |
| Retail | Gold | 2345 | Leave | M2 |
| Retail | Gold | 3456 | Leave | M3 |
| Retail | Gold | 4567 | Leave | M3 |
| Retail | Silver | 5678 | Leave | M1 |
| Retail | Silver | 6789 | Leave | M2 |
| Retail | Silver | 7890 | Leave | M2 |

I am unable to copy my original for loop code as it runs up to two pages :D. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Changing to list comprehension or lambda will probably not make it much more efficient. You need a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Any thoughts on better ways? Open to suggestions.

Comment: Without seeing the code, how can anyone possibly tell how to do it better?

Comment: And if you're really looking for more efficient iteration, consider using pandas.

Comment: I also don't really understand what you're doing in the first place. Could you explain more clearly how the output relates to the inputs?

Comment: I am essentially joining the Client Mapping with details to determine whether a client will leave or stay and if so which month. Take Client ID 1234, who is tagged as Staying from M1 (4 employees * 0.3) where Client 3456, 4567 are tagged as Leaving at M3 (one is from left over residual decimal spots from using floor and other from 0.4*4)

Comment: **This must be done by using math floor function** Floor of what? Are you multiplying `M#` by `Client_Category_Count`? Anyway, pandas can do joins automatically.

Comment: Put these clarifications in the question, not a comment.

Comment: That is correct. I am using pandas math floor function and iterrows for loops and if conditions to currently calculate the months..